# Layouts and Mouse events

Tags: java, events, layout, swt

I'm trying to create a custom slider with SWT, but I have a strange result, I wish I'm missing something here, I would like to have a Composite with an internal canvas that has a margin all around so 15 top, left right and bottom.
Something similar to this:

[image]

So I wrote a main like this:

Main.java

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class Main {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    shell.setSize(400,400);
    CustomSlider slider= new CustomSlider(shell, SWT.NONE);


    shell.pack();
    shell.open ();

    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

And the customSlider class that extends Composite:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget;

public class CustomSlider extends Composite {
    private Canvas progressBar;
    private Rectangle progressBarRect;
    private int knobSize=15;
    private Point thisSize;
    private boolean hover=false;
    public CustomSlider(Composite arg0, int arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        thisSize= new Point(400, 50);
        setSize(400, 50);
        setBackground(arg0.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_MAGENTA));
        GridLayout gl= new GridLayout(1,false);
        setLayout(gl);
        setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));


        progressBar = new Canvas(this, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout gl2= new GridLayout(1,false);
        gl2.marginBottom=knobSize;
        gl2.marginTop=knobSize;
        gl2.marginLeft=knobSize;
        gl2.marginRight=knobSize;
        gl2.marginWidth=knobSize;
        gl2.marginHeight=knobSize;
        progressBar.setLayout(gl2);
        GridData gd=new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);

        progressBar.setLayoutData(gd);
        progressBar.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent arg0) {
                Canvas canvasProgress=(Canvas)arg0.widget;
                progressBarRect= canvasProgress.getBounds();

                GC gc=arg0.gc;
                gc.setForeground(canvasProgress.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
                if (hover){
                gc.setBackground(canvasProgress.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
                }else{
                    gc.setBackground(canvasProgress.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
                }
                gc.fillRectangle(progressBarRect);
                gc.drawRectangle(progressBarRect);

            }
        });


         Listener listener = new Listener() {
              public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                  System.out.println("---------------");
                  System.out.println("Canvas:"+((Canvas)event.widget).getBounds());
                  System.out.println("Composite:"+((Canvas)event.widget).getParent().getBounds());
                  System.out.println("Shell:"+((Canvas)event.widget).getParent().getParent().getBounds());
                  Display display=((Widget)event.widget).getDisplay();
                switch (event.type) {

                case SWT.MouseHover:
                    if (progressBarRect.contains(new Point(event.x, event.y))){

                          hover=true;
                      }else{

                          hover=false;
                      }
                      break;

                case SWT.MouseDown:

                  break;
                case SWT.MouseMove:
                    if (progressBarRect.contains(new Point(event.x, event.y))){

                          hover=true;
                      }else{

                          hover=false;
                      }

                  break;
                case SWT.MouseEnter:
                    if (progressBarRect.contains(new Point(event.x, event.y))){

                          hover=true;
                      }else{

                          hover=false;
                      }

                  break; 
                case SWT.MouseExit:
                    if (progressBarRect.contains(new Point(event.x, event.y))){
                        System.out.println("progressBarRect:"+progressBarRect);
                        System.out.println("Point"+new Point(event.x, event.y));
                        System.out.println("HOVER!");
                          hover=true;
                      }else{
                          System.out.println("OUT!");
                          hover=false;
                      }

                  break;   
                case SWT.MouseUp:

                  break;


                }
                display.asyncExec(() -> progressBar.redraw());
              }
            };
            progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
            progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, listener);
            progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, listener);
            progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseExit, listener);
            progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, listener);
            progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseHover, listener);



    }
    public Point getThisSize() {
        return thisSize;
    }
    public void setThisSize(Point thisSize) {
        this.thisSize = thisSize;
    }


}
```

Now, first thing is the result doesn't match what I want , it seems the margins are not take into account, or better only two (top and left):

[image]

Second, the events result in unexpected results: the MouseExit event says I'm still hover the canvas, even if I'm out of the composite! :S

[image]

Can you please help me to understand what is going on here?

Thank you in advance...

**EDIT**
Following Greg's suggestions I edit my code as following:

Main:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class Main {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    //shell.setSize(400,400);
    CustomSlider2 slider= new CustomSlider2(shell, SWT.NONE);


    shell.pack();
    shell.open ();

    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

and Custom Slider become CustomSlider2:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget;

public class CustomSlider2 extends Composite {
    private Canvas progressBar;
    private Rectangle progressBarRect;
    private int knobSize=15;

    private boolean hover=false;
    public CustomSlider2(Composite arg0, int arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        setBackground(arg0.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_MAGENTA));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));

        progressBar = new Canvas(this, SWT.CENTER);
        final GridData gd=new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        gd.widthHint = 100;
        gd.heightHint = 50;
        GridLayout gl= new GridLayout();
        gl.numColumns=1;
        gl.marginWidth=knobSize;
        gl.marginHeight=knobSize;
        progressBar.setLayoutData(gd);
        progressBar.setLayout(gl);



        progressBar.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent arg0) {
                Canvas canvasProgress=(Canvas)arg0.widget;
                Rectangle clientArea= canvasProgress.getBounds();
                progressBarRect=new Rectangle(clientArea.x, clientArea.y, clientArea.x + clientArea.width - 1, clientArea.y + clientArea.height - 1);
                GC gc=arg0.gc;
                gc.setForeground(canvasProgress.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
                if (hover){
                    gc.setBackground(canvasProgress.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
                }else{
                    gc.setBackground(canvasProgress.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
                }
                gc.fillRectangle(progressBarRect);
                gc.drawRectangle(progressBarRect);

            }
        });


        Listener listener = new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                System.out.println("---------------");
                System.out.println("Canvas:"+((Canvas)event.widget).getBounds());
                System.out.println("Composite:"+((Canvas)event.widget).getParent().getBounds());
                System.out.println("Shell:"+((Canvas)event.widget).getParent().getParent().getBounds());
                Display display=((Widget)event.widget).getDisplay();
                switch (event.type) {
                case SWT.MouseEnter:
                    hover=true;
                    break; 
                case SWT.MouseExit:
                    hover=false;    
                    break;   


                }
                display.asyncExec(() -> progressBar.redraw());
            }
        };

        progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseExit, listener);
        progressBar.addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, listener);


    }


}
```

So the event problem seems to be fixed but not the layout one... I still don't have the margin around the canvas...

Comment: Don't mix `setSize` (or `setBounds`) with layouts - the layout will override the size.

Comment: Hi Greg, but I didn't mix it, I used set size for the Composite (CustomSlider) and let SWT decide the bounds of the Canvas but I told SWT to use a grid layout for the Canvas n order to have margins all around... What is wrong with that?

Comment: I have done a test even commenting out the setSize on the Composite the result doesn't change, the margins are respected only for top and left... :(

Comment: Your shell has a GridLayout, that will override the CustomSlider size. I''m not saying it is the only problem here.

Comment: Hi Greg, so because a Composite without a layout is not shown , it means setSize should be never used on it? it sound strange to me...Sorry for the stupid question but I'm trying to learn...

Comment: If you don't use layouts at all anywhere in the app you can use setSize and setBounds. When you use layouts you don't use them. You can specify size hints on GridLayout. For custom controls you might override `computeSize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using layouts you can use the layout width and height hints to set a suggested size for the control. So here you might use:

```
final GridData gd=new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
gd.widthHint = 400;
gd.heightHint = 50;
progressBar.setLayoutData(gd);
```

In `paintControl` you are using `getBounds` which gives you the full size of the control including borders added by the layout. But operations such as `fillRectangle` always draw in the 'client area' which excludes the borders. So your paint should be something like:

```
@Override
public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
  Canvas canvasProgress = (Canvas)event.widget;
  Rectangle clientArea = canvasProgress.getClientArea(); // Client area

  .. set colors

  gc.fillRectangle(clientArea.x, clientArea.y, clientArea.x + clientArea.width - 1, clientArea.y + clientArea.height - 1);
  gc.drawRectangle(clientArea.x, clientArea.y, clientArea.x + clientArea.width - 1, clientArea.y + clientArea.height - 1);
}
```

For the mouse movement there is no need to check the positions in the event. MouseExit is only called when the mouse leaves your control.

Comment: Hi Greg, the problem with the Events seems to be fixed, but not the one with the layout... I still don't have the margins around the canvas...(I have edited my question with the new code...)

Comment: You are still using `getBounds` in `paintControl`, this must be `getClientArea`.